# how to export 72 dpi and get normal quality image

Tags: vector, export, dpi

I have designed portfolio at 72 dpi, so when I exported as pdf got horrible quality. Can I do anything to get normal quality? I exported png which is fine when displayed in browser but in picture viewer you have to zoom (because it's too long)

Comment: Why was your 72 dpi alright while designing but "horrible" as a PDF? Is it because you are zooming in on the PDF – and expected the images to be better than the originals?

Answer (score 2):

Unless *everything* you do is for screen rendering (web/Mobile) then you should design at a higher resolution, and down-save to lower resolutions for output. Even some mobile devices require designing at more than 72ppi.

There's really no fantastic method for making a low resolution image appear good at a higher resolution. You can *always* reduce quality, but it's nearly impossible to *improve* quality in any sort of satisfactory manner.

- [How to upscale a non-vector PNG pixel image without lossiness or blur?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92049/how-to-upscale-a-non-vector-png-pixel-image-without-lossiness-or-blur)
- [How can I 'blow up' small pixel art?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65374/how-can-i-blow-up-small-pixel-art)
- [How can I upscale my low resolution to hi-res image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67500/how-can-i-upscale-my-low-resolution-to-hi-res-image)
- [How can I increase the size of a .jpeg without losing quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21568/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-jpeg-without-losing-quality)
- [How to resize an image without losing quality](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/how-to-resize-an-image-without-losing-quality)

Comment: Absolutely. One way to make this work, though, without any resampling is to place the images on the page using e.g. inDesign at `(pixel dimension)/300 inches`. A full screen 1080p image is 1920x1080, which is 300 ppi @ 6.4 inches x 3.6 inches. Best possible quality without resampling.

Comment: One can always scale down without resampling to increase *effective* ppi -- that, to me, is not the same as attempting to enlarge a low resolution file. And I don't think a reduction in dimensions is what the questioner was after.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

If you designed it at 72dpi you CAN increase it to 120-300dpi but then you will get horrible pixelation and artifacts.

You should always design LARGER than you intend and scale down if needed. That way you won't lose as much quality during the process.